# Is the fuction $g:\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} $ given by $g(m,n)=14m+21n$ injective?

Tags: functions

Is my proof correct?

**Proof**:

Suppose $g(m,n)=g(p,q) \, $ for some arbitrary $(m,n),(p,q) \in$ $\mathbb{Z}$ x $\mathbb{Z}$

Then $14m+21n=14p+21q$ $\rightarrow m=p \, ,n=q \rightarrow (m,n)=(p,q)$

$\therefore $ the function $g$ is injective

Comment: By what logic did you go from $14m+21n=14p+21q\;$to$\;m=p,\;n=q$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not correct.

For example, $g(0,0) = g(21,-14)$.

Comment: Thank you, can you help me with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2451999/is-the-fuction-g-mathbbz-x-mathbbz-rightarrow-mathbbz-given-by-g

Answer (score 2):

The function is not injective in $(Z*Z)$: if $(m,n)=(0,0)$, $g(m,n) = 0$.
And if $(p,q)=(-21,14)$, $g(p,q)=-21*14+14*21=0$.