# Is the function $g:\mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} $ given by $g(m,n)=14m+21n$ onto?

Tags: functions

Is my proof correct?

**Proof**:

1)  $\, g(m,n)=y$

Let $ y =1 $ then $m=0 $ and $n=1/21 \rightarrow (0,1/21)\notin $ $ \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$

$\therefore $ the function $g$ is not onto

Comment: This argument makes no sense.  Try to write down some numbers in the image...does it look like you get all the integers?

Comment: You had a huge conceptual mistake. You need to verify to **all** pais (m,n) if $g(m,n) \neq 1$.

Comment: "Let $y=1$ then $m=1$" is an erroneous deduction.

Comment: Proper notation is $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z,$ not $\mathbb Z$ x $\mathbb Z.$ I edited accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$g(m,n) = 14m + 21n = y$$

You say that if $y=1$ then $m=0$ and  $n=1/21.$

But you could just as easily say that if $y=1$ then $m=1/14$ and $n=0.$

And $m=1/28$ and $n=1/42$ also yields $y=1.$

You need to show that among all the possible values of $m$ and $n$ that yield $y=1,$ there are no instances in which $m$ and $n$ are integers.

You could say $g(m,n) = 14m + 21 n = 7(2m+3n) = y,$ so $y$ must be a multiple of $7,$ i.e. a member of the set $\{0,\pm7,\pm14,\pm21,\pm28,\pm35,\ldots\}.$

The function $g$ is not onto because its image fails to contain any integers that are not in that set.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not, $5$ is not image. If it would be, then $7\mid 5$, a contradiction. And, this is not the only example. Every $a$ which is not divisible by $7$ is not in a range of this function.

Answer (score 3):

Note $gcd(14, 21) = 7$ so by [Bezout lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), there are $s, t \in \mathbb{Z}$
such that $14 s + 21 t = 7$, so $7 \mathbb{Z} = \{7 k \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\} \subseteq  im(g)$.

Let $A = im(g) \cap \mathbb{Z}^{+} \neq \varnothing$. $\mathbb{N}$ is well ordered, so we can define $a = \min A \in A$ and we can write $a = g(\alpha, \beta) = 14 \alpha + 21 \beta, \,\, \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{Z}$.

First, i will prove that $im(g) \subseteq a \mathbb{Z}$. Let $b \in im(g)$, we have $u,v \in \mathbb{Z}$, $b = 14u+21v$. On the other hand, there are $q, r \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $b = q \, a + r$. Then $$r = b- q a = (14u + 21v) - (14 q\alpha +21 q\beta) = 14 (u - q \alpha) + 21 (v + q \beta) = g (u-q\alpha, v-q\beta) \in A$$ But $r < a = \min A$, then $r=0$ and $b = q\, a \in a \mathbb{Z}$.

Now, I will prove that $a =7$ in the exactly the same way (we can prove it together). There are $Q, R \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $7 = Q \,a + R$ with $0 \leq R <a$. In this case, we write $$R = 7 - q \, a = (14 s + 21t) - (14 \alpha + 21 \beta)  = 14(s - \alpha) + 21(t - \beta) = g(s - \alpha, t - \beta) \in A$$

But $R < a = \min A$, so $R =0$ and $a=7q$. We know that $0 < a \leq 7$, so $a = 7$.

We proved that $im(g) = 7 \mathbb{Z} \neq \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: It's not the easiest proof (see Michael's one), but I like the ideias here (use Bezout lemma and division, it's the way to prove that any ideal is principal).